# Traer datos de Mysql Pasando Atributos desde variables con php

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero traer datos de `msql` que pertenezcan a cierto `codigoId` y estén entre ciertas fechas para ello estoy utilizando este `query`.

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordint 
 WHERE codigoId = '".$_POST["codigoId"]."' 
 BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'";
```

Pero no me esta trayendo los datos correctos, Mis tablas serian:
`codigoId`, `f_aprueba`, necesito que si hay datos entre las fechas que estoy ingresando con variables y pertenezcan al `codigoID` que también estoy trayendo con variable que me muestre solo esos, pero no se si estoy haciendo uso correcto de la condición **BETWEEN**

Alguien que me pueda apoyar, soy algo novato con traer datos en base a condiciones.

Comment: Te falta agregar la columna donde estas buscando las fechas.

Comment: @alanfcm Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudarías indicándome la sintaxis que debo seguir para esto, ya que busque info en la web pero no he econtrado nada relacionado

Comment: Como se llama la columna que contiene las fechas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu sintaxis es incorrecta.  Te falta agregar el nombre de la columna donde tienes almacenadas las fechas.  Algo asi:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordint 
    WHERE codigoId = '".$_POST["codigoId"]."' 
    AND f_aprueba BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'";
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta, fue de gran ayuda!